# How can I add a filter to my screen?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, screen, filter, color

Say I'm bored of my screen looking as boring as it normally does, is there a way to add a filter to all the colours on the screen (like an Instagram filter or even something simpler like a red light filter)?

**Original**

[image: original]

**Filtered**

[image: glow]
[image: cross-processed]
[image: greyscale]

Comment: There are these blue-light filter apps which you could use. A quick google search will get you their links. One of them has different colours, and I guess that is somehow related. There is one by the developer Hardy-Infinity, and that has the feature I'm mentioning about.

Comment: Related (has my answer) : [How to add screen filter with tasker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around, I unearthed some interesting developer settings that significantly jazz up my homescreen. The added benefit of this in-built solution is it doesn't block app installs :)

[image: here]

There's also the colour inversion option under accessibility settings

[image: inversion]

I'd post a screenshot of my new homescreen but it seems the filter isn't reflected in screenshots.

Comment: What you are using is no real overlay, but rather an accessibility setting. It kind of works, but is not very flexible. Nice idea, though, I would not have thought about that.