# Overlay a semi-transparent image on top of the Camera app

Tags: camera, overlay

I'd like to take a picture in the exact spot as another photo I've take a while back.

To help lining up the shot, I wonder if it would be possible to overlay the camera app with a semi-transparent version of the older photo?

Comment: You can crop the picture and then create a scene in Tasker to load that picture which should be shown as an overlay when your camera app is active. This might give you an idea: [How to add screen filter with tasker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125458)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Overlay Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.OverlayCamera.android.app.quick) app on Play Store. I tried it, and it matches exactly with your description.

Comment: Suggestion - you cold improve your answer by providing a summary of features and/or screenshots.

Comment: This does not install on Google Pixel 7